# Create Datetime object from string

Tags: php, string, datetime

I have a situation where I need to create a Datetime object from a string.
The issue comes when I don't have consistency in the pattern of the string representing the date.
These are examples of my data:

```
07/17/2012
2013/03/11
17/05/2015
17/17/2015
```

As you can see, the last one is invalid no matter what, because there is no 17 month, but the first 3 are valid depending on the month position(and of course, the year)

My question: is there any way(pretty sure through regex) to make a function with the date string as parameter that return the datetime object. If the string is not valid, return: 1/1/1970...

Comment: What about ambiguous dates like 4/6/2015 ?

Comment: You have to think for a solution for _how_ your program can differentiate the different formats.

Comment: For example: count the number of characters before the first `'/'`. If it is 4 you know its the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue comes when I don't have consistency in the pattern of the string representing the date

for this purpose, php offers `strtotime()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Example usage:

```
   $str1 = "2015-06-04 16:00";
   $str2 = "06/04/2015 4 pm";
   $str3 = "04.06.2015 16:00";

   $actualDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($str1));
   echo $actualDate."<br />";
   $actualDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($str2));
   echo $actualDate."<br />";
   $actualDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($str3));
   echo $actualDate."<br />";

   //all will produce "2015-06-04 16:00:00"
```

as a bonus, `strtotime` also supports "insane" expressions like

```
$actualDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("06/04/2015 + 1 day - 8 hours")); 
echo $actualDate."<br />";
// "2015-06-04 16:00:00"
```

and many more such as "monday this week", "tuesday next week", "first monday of january 2038" and the like.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create DateTime Object with your string values. It will throw exception if the date format is not valid, then you can just catch it and return your 1/1/1971

```
try {
    $dateTime = new DateTime('17/17/2015');
    return $dateTime;
} catch (Exception $e) {
   return '1/1/1971';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

```
$myDate = '17/17/2015';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $myDate);

if (DateTime::getLastErrors()['warning_count'] >= 1) {
    // Invalid
} else {
    // Valid date
}
```

Comment: The problem is I can't asure this format: 
    'd/m/Y' 
in 
    createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $myDate)
Take a look to the data examples

Comment: You could use `strtotime`, then?

Comment: If you allow completely custom dates you will always encounter problems. E.g., 1/2/15 might be 1st February or the 2nd January.